# Crystal Reports 2011 time -24 hours

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a report that pulls all the data from the previous day's production.  The problem with that is our operations is two shifts and information from second shift is entered around 230 AM the next morning (ex. production was the 15th, but they didn't enter data until 16th at 230AM).

This is the formula that I used:
`date({REJECTS.PROD_DATE})=dateadd('d',-1,currentdate)`.

I tried this formula with the same results:  `date({REJECTS.TIME_STAMP})=dateadd('h',-24,currentdatetime)`.

I have verified that REJECTS.TIME_STAMP is a datetime field.

Any help would be great,

Thanks
Trevor

Comment: Your formulas reference 2 different datetime fields.  What's the difference between them?  I recommend picking just one and sticking with it.  Also, does your chosen datetime field include the time or does it just default to midnight?

Comment: what is your exact requirement? you need previous day or next day... if it is previous day then your formula is correct.. what is the problem with formula?

Comment: Rejects.prod_date was only a date field, that is why I changed to Rejects.time_stamp.  It looks to be midnight to midnight.

Comment: What I want to happen from this report is to report everything in a 24 hour range from when it is ran.  If it is ran at 3AM, show me everything that was produce from 3AM the day before to 3AM of curentday.
Thanks  
Trevor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your report's record-selection formula:

```
// timestamp should be new than 24 hours before the current date/time (calculated dynamically)
{REJECTS.TIME_STAMP} >= DateAdd("h", -24, CurrentDateTime)

// include other restrictions as necessary
AND ...
```

Comment: If I run this report at 5/20/2014 10:00AM, it should show information from 5/19/2014 10:00AM to 5/20/2014 10:00AM.

Comment: @Greentr: this will give you the lower bound.  the upper bound would be the data (what is in the system at the time the report is generated).  if you need to run it as of a different date/time, then the report would need to be parameterized.

Comment: Thank-you all for your help.  @Craig: your formula works great...now that I deleted my old formula from running at a different location, it produces the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be:

1. Create a `String`  parameter and give default values for `24` hours... in the required format (`either half hour format` or `Hour format`).

If you require check the [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/205398/Crystal-Report-Filtering-Using-Selection-Parameter) for parameters.

2 use below formula in `Record Select Expert`

```
{REJECTS.TIME_STAMP}>=Cdatetime(Cdate(dateadd('d',-1,currentdate)),Ctime({?tme})) and
   {REJECTS.TIME_STAMP}<Cdatetime(CDate(dateadd('d',0,currentdate)),Ctime({?time})) and
```

Now when you run the report you will be prompted for time.. select the time and you query will be formed as required by you.

Comment: That is the twist I forgot to mention, it is an automated report.  It can't have any prompts.

Comment: I didn't get the concept of automated reports? can you elaborate more on that.... if you can't add parameters then how can you add formulas